# How to modify Johnson's algorithm to print all graph cycles in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph, networkx

I would like to modify the networkx implementation(https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/algorithms/cycles.html#simple_cycles) of Johnson's algorithm for finding all elementary cycles in a graph (also copied below) and print them in a text file. I want to make this modification because i use large graphs and i get a memory error because the list which save the cycles is huge.

```
def simple_cycles(G):

    def _unblock(thisnode,blocked,B):
        stack=set([thisnode])
        while stack:
            node=stack.pop()
            if node in blocked:
                blocked.remove(node)
                stack.update(B[node])
                B[node].clear()

    # Johnson's algorithm requires some ordering of the nodes.
    # We assign the arbitrary ordering given by the strongly connected comps
    # There is no need to track the ordering as each node removed as processed.
    subG = type(G)(G.edges_iter()) # save the actual graph so we can mutate it here
                              # We only take the edges because we do not want to
                              # copy edge and node attributes here.
    sccs = list(nx.strongly_connected_components(subG))
    while sccs:
        scc=sccs.pop()
        # order of scc determines ordering of nodes
        startnode = scc.pop()
        # Processing node runs "circuit" routine from recursive version
        path=[startnode]
        blocked = set() # vertex: blocked from search?
        closed = set() # nodes involved in a cycle
        blocked.add(startnode)
        B=defaultdict(set) # graph portions that yield no elementary circuit
        stack=[ (startnode,list(subG[startnode])) ]  # subG gives component nbrs
        while stack:
            thisnode,nbrs = stack[-1]
            if nbrs:
                nextnode = nbrs.pop()
#                    print thisnode,nbrs,":",nextnode,blocked,B,path,stack,startnode
#                    f=raw_input("pause")
                if nextnode == startnode:
                    yield path[:]
                    closed.update(path)
#                        print "Found a cycle",path,closed
                elif nextnode not in blocked:
                    path.append(nextnode)
                    stack.append( (nextnode,list(subG[nextnode])) )
                    closed.discard(nextnode)
                    blocked.add(nextnode)
                    continue
            # done with nextnode... look for more neighbors
            if not nbrs:  # no more nbrs
                if thisnode in closed:
                    _unblock(thisnode,blocked,B)
                else:
                    for nbr in subG[thisnode]:
                        if thisnode not in B[nbr]:
                            B[nbr].add(thisnode)
                stack.pop()
#                assert path[-1]==thisnode
                path.pop()
        # done processing this node
        subG.remove_node(startnode)
        H=subG.subgraph(scc)  # make smaller to avoid work in SCC routine
        sccs.extend(list(nx.strongly_connected_components(H)))
```

Of course, I'd also accept a suggestion that differs from the implementation above but runs in similar time. Also, my project uses networkx, so feel free to use any other function from that library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The networkx.simple_cycles() function is already a generator.  You can just iterate over the cycles and print them to a file like this

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.cycle_graph(5).to_directed()

In [3]: with open('foo','w') as f:
   ...:     for c in nx.simple_cycles(G):
   ...:         print(c, file=f)
   ...:         

In [4]: cat foo
[0, 4]
[0, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
```